# Sorting understanding issue in a Multidimenssional Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, columnsorting

I am trying to sort a multidimensional array. The array contains City & Population. These are displayed in a table.I want to sort the Population column in a ascending order. I do understand, that the procedure is `sort($array_variable)`, but i don't know how to print them after sorting. Please help me educating in this matter. The program is as follows

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table, tr, td, th {
            border:1px solid blue;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $data=array (
        array('New York','Washington',8008278),
        array('Los Angeles','California',3694820),
        array('Chicago','Illinois',2896016),
        array('Houston','Texas',1953631),
        array('Philadelphia','Philadelphia',1517550),
        array('Pheonix','Arizona',1321045),
        array('San Diego','California',1223400),
        array('Dallas','Texas',188580),
        array('San Antonio','Texas',144646),
        array('Detroit','Michigan',951270),                        
    );
    print '<table>';

    print '<th>'; print "City"; print '</th>';
    print '<th>'; print "State"; print '</th>';
    print '<th>'; print "Population"; print '</th>';

    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[0][0]; print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[0][1]; print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[0][2]; print '</td>';
    print '</tr>';

    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[1][0]; print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[1][1]; print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[1][2]; print '</td>';
    print '</tr>';

    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[2][0]; print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[2][1]; print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[2][2]; print '</td>';
    print '</tr>';

    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[3][0]; print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[3][1]; print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[3][2]; print '</td>';
    print '</tr>';

    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[4][0]; print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[4][1]; print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[4][2]; print '</td>';
    print '</tr>';

    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[5][0]; print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[5][1]; print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[5][2]; print '</td>';
    print '</tr>';

    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[6][0]; print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[6][1]; print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[6][2]; print '</td>';
    print '</tr>';

    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[7][0]; print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[7][1]; print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[7][2]; print '</td>';
    print '</tr>';

    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[8][0]; print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[8][1]; print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[8][2]; print '</td>';
    print '</tr>';

    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[9][0]; print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[9][1]; print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[9][2]; print '</td>';
    print '</tr>';

    print '<tr>';
    print '<td colspan=2>'; print "Total Population is:";  
    print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $data[0][2]+$data[1][2]+$data[2][2]+$data[3][2]+$data[4][2]+$data[5][2]+$data[6][2]+$data[7][2]+$data[8][2]+$data[9][2]; print '</td>';
    print '</tr>';

    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'; print sort($data); print '</td>';
    print '</tr>';        
    print '</table>';
    ?>
</body>
```

Sorry for the long program, a noob here. As you see. I have given a `sort()` function, but it doesn't giving the desired output. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a loop to print out the data. Also I'd create a class `City` and use `usort` to compare based on the `population` property. Something like this:

```
<?php

class City{
    public $population;
    public $name;
    public $state;

    public function __construct($name,$state,$population) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->state = $state;
    $this->population = $population;
    }

}
$data=array (          
        new City('New York','Washington',8008278),
        new City('Los Angeles','California',3694820),
        new City('Chicago','Illinois',2896016),
        new City('Houston','Texas',1953631),
        new City('Philadelphia','Philadelphia',1517550),
        new City('Pheonix','Arizona',1321045),
        new City('San Diego','California',1223400),
        new City('Dallas','Texas',188580),
        new City('San Antonio','Texas',144646),
        new City('Detroit','Michigan',951270)              
    );


usort($data, function($a, $b)
{
    return $a->population < $b->population;
});

print '<table>';
    print '<tr>';
    print '<th>'; print "City"; print '</th>';
    print '<th>'; print "State"; print '</th>';
    print '<th>'; print "Population"; print '</th>';
    print '</tr>';


foreach($data as $currCity){    
    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'; print $currCity->name; print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $currCity->state; print '</td>';
    print '<td>'; print $currCity->population; print '</td>';
    print '</tr>';

}
```

Comment: That work like a charm, thank you for your time. I really appreciate.

Comment: @SandeepRoy happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<table>
  <tr> 
    <th> City </th>
    <th> State </th>
    <th> Population </th>
  </tr>
  <?php 
   $totalPop = 0; 
   foreach($data as $d) { ?>
      <tr> 
         <th> <?php echo $d[0]; ?> </th>
         <th> <?php echo $d[1]; ?> </th>
         <th> <?php echo $d[2]; $totalPop += $d[2]; ?> </th>
      </tr>
  <?php } ?>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"> Total Population is: </td>
    <td><?php echo $totalPop; ?></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time to reply. I appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
<?php
$data = array(
    array('New York', 'Washington', 8008278),
    array('Los Angeles', 'California', 3694820),
    array('Chicago', 'Illinois', 2896016),
    array('Houston', 'Texas', 1953631),
    array('Philadelphia', 'Philadelphia', 1517550),
    array('Pheonix', 'Arizona', 1321045),
    array('San Diego', 'California', 1223400),
    array('Dallas', 'Texas', 188580),
    array('San Antonio', 'Texas', 144646),
    array('Detroit', 'Michigan', 951270),
);

usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    return $a[2] - $b[2];
});
?>
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>Population</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $totalPopulation=0;
foreach($data as $d)
{
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $d[0];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $d[1];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $d[2];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $totalPopulation = $totalPopulation+$d[2];
}
?>
    <tr><td>Total Population</td><td colspan="2"><?php echo $totalPopulation; ?></td></tr>
</table>
```